# ARKit – 3d transform of face

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

On [this page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/content_anchors/tracking_and_visualizing_faces) I can read:

> Live camera video texture-mapped onto the ARKit face mesh, with which you can create effects that appear to distort the user’s real face in 3D.

I haven't found much sample and extra documentation about this.
Is it possible to distort the face itself in 3D with ARKit? Like changing chin shape and such?

If yes, briefly on a conceptual level, how could this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't distort the canonical mesh used by Metal (***ARSCNFaceGeometry***). However, if you intend to dynamically distort a facial mask, you have two options:

- create an animated face model in 3D authoring app
- use SceneKit's [SCNMorpher](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnmorpher) with its morph targets